# Cannot find plugin "karma-webpack"

Tags: karma-runner, karma-webpack

I am struggling with testing of libraries in browsers by schema Karma, Webpack, Babel.
Running the Karma

```sh
 npx karma start karma.conf.js --single-run --browsers PhantomJS
```

I receive the following.

```sh
13 12 2020 11:58:16.370:ERROR [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-webpack".
  Did you forget to install it?
  npm install karma-webpack --save-dev
```

These packages are installed locally. I also have installed them globally. Still the same.
There is my karma.conf.js

```js
const webpackConfig = require('./testing.webpack.js');
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',
        coverageReporter: {
            dir: 'tmp/coverage/',
            reporters: [
                { type: 'html', subdir: 'report-html' },
                { type: 'lcov', subdir: 'report-lcov' }
            ],
            instrumenterOptions: {
                istanbul: { noCompact: true }
            }
        },
        files: [
            'spec/**/*.spec.js'
        ],
        frameworks: ['should', 'jasmine', 'mocha'],
        reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage'],
        preprocessors: {
            'spec/**/*.spec.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
        },
        plugins: [
            'karma-webpack',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-mocha',
            'karma-should',
            'karma-coverage',
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
            'karma-mocha-reporter',
            'karma-sourcemap-loader'
        ],
        webpack: webpackConfig,
        webpackMiddleware: {
           stats: 'errors-only'
        }
    });

    return config;
};
```

The error is confusing. Because it is easy to resolve according to the error output but it has not to be resolved.
I will be pleased with a tip.

Comment: What version of webpack are you using? There is [an issue reported](https://github.com/ryanclark/karma-webpack/issues/450) that looks similar.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This comment has resolved my issue. https://github.com/ryanclark/karma-webpack/issues/450#issuecomment-702052637

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was an issue of incompatible packages. A similar issue is reported [here](https://github.com/ryanclark/karma-webpack/issues/450). [A comment](https://github.com/ryanclark/karma-webpack/issues/450#issuecomment-702052637) helped me.
Karma 5.2.3 is used. Karma-webpack: was latest:4.0.2, **works with dev: 5.0.0-alpha.3.0**, next: 5.0.0-alpha.5 is available.

Comment: That is why I use Webpack 4 and another Karma default proposed packages.

Comment: karma-webpack 5.0.0 is now available